# MU domain mapping login issue

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

From [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/261087/3206), a MU site has the following in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

If I try to login to a child site @ http://example2.net/wp-login.php, I receive the error:

> The constant "COOKIE_DOMAIN" is defined (probably in wp-config.php).
>   Please remove or comment out that define() line.

If I comment out:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
```

I receive the error:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must
>   enable cookies to use WordPress

The site the answer above refers to is working with the definitions above.

Any ideas why the same definitions are not working on this earlier installed Wordpress? (perhaps from around `v4.3`?)

Comment: You are defining "COOKIE_DOMAIN" twice in your above code. Remove one of them.

Comment: Thanks @Spartacus. I now no longer receive the cookie error. I have reset the password on example.com, but this does not let me login @ `example2.net/wp-login.php`. I receive no error at the login screen, it just reloads the same page.

Comment: Turn on the debug mode and check if there is any error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely it worked for me (on more than one multisites) to set SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL to false. To be honest, I hadn't had time to investigate further why ...

`define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure sunrise.php is in the wp-content directory and that you have defined the following in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
```

With sunrise on, you should not define COOKIE_DOMAIN anywhere else as it handles that dynamically on all mapped domains.

My guess is that either you don't have `define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );` or you don't have `sunrise.php` installed correctly. Another thing to check would be that the domain is correctly configured in wp-admin.

Comment: Thanks tubes. I didn't have `SUNRISE` defined in `wp-config.php`. I do now and the issue remains.

Comment: Hi Steve! I thought your answer below using wordpress-mu-domain-mapping indicates you solved the problem? What issue remains after following all the steps in https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/#installation ?

Comment: This solution worked for me when I was experiencing the following: 1.I could login/access my main site   2.I could access my secondary sites but not login.

Side note, I commented out sunset and added COOKIE_DOMAIN line. so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this. It turned out it was the sunrise code that was causing the conflict:

```
<?php
if ( !defined( 'SUNRISE_LOADED' ) )
    define( 'SUNRISE_LOADED', 1 );

if ( defined( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN' ) ) {
    die( 'The constant "COOKIE_DOMAIN" is defined (probably in wp-config.php). Please remove or comment out that define() line.' );
}
```

...

I commented out the sunrise in wp-config.php

`//define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );`

And added

`define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

before the `/*` That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ comment.

That made me login to my multisite again and all sub sites, but worked like a charm!!!

Really hope this helps someone else struggling with this very very frustrating issue. :)

Comment: When I add that `define`, my website has a white screen with a single error: `The constant "COOKIE_DOMAIN" is defined (probably in wp-config.php). Please remove or comment out that define() line.`

Answer (score 0):

the first error come from additionnal code which would probably not be usefull with the actual WordPress version (4.7.3 today)

try to comment the line `define("SUNRISE"...` in `wp-config.php`

Comment: Thanks. I have reset the password on example.com, but this does not let me login @ `example2.net/wp-login.php`. I receive no error at the login screen, it just reloads the same page.

Comment: try to desactivate all plugins (reagulars ones and must-use ones) to see if there is a difference

Answer (score -1):

I bypassed the inbuilt Wordpress domain mapping, and instead used the [Wordpress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin, which proved to be much easier to maintain and troubleshoot.

Comment: I downvoted because the error don't come from the inbuilt Wordpress domain mapping then it comes of a plugin or other external code. Moreover the plugin `Wordpress MU Domain Mapping` if for 3.0 versions then it cannot solve the problem

Comment: but it did solve the problem....?